# Kotlin map function returns a Stream and is not a Java equivalent for collect()

Tags: kotlin, java-stream

`map` returns a Stream instead a `List<Media>`. So the assignment `product.media = cleanedMedia` will not work. I have to use `collect` here to make it work. But I often saw people saying that `map` is the equivalent to `collect` for Java. (stated here for example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-stream-vs-kotlin)

```
    fun cleanup(product: Product) {
        val cleanedMedia = product.media.stream()
                .filter { "failed" == it.purpose }
                .map {it}
        product.media = cleanedMedia
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a purely Kotlin `List`

In your `Product` class, make sure to remove the `import java.util.List` to use Kotlin's list.

```
class Product {
  var media: List<Media> = listOf()
}
```

Then, you can simply write the following:

```
fun cleanup(product: Product) {
  product.media = product.media.filter { "failed" == it.purpose }
}
```

Comment: Can u show me exactly whatyou mean. When I omit `stream` the syntax goes red

Comment: From this remark, I suppose that you have a `java.util.List`, not a Kotlin `List`. Transform your java List to a kotlin list and it'll work.

Comment: How to transform that?

Comment: its coming from a java library?

Answer (score 0):

> But I often saw people saying that `map` is the equivalent to `collect` for Java.

First of all: kotlin has multiple schemes for item iteration:

- Default: with materialized collection. E.g. all operators return final collection, for example - [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html).
- Kotlin Sequences: they are looks like Java streams, e.g. they returns lazy iterator. Please check the [same methods here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html).
- Kotlin Coroutines also have [map function](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/map.html). It is streaming operator and returns Flux.

Therefore:
* Kotlin Sequences looks like Java Streams, however byte code is cooked during the compilation. So formally implementation is different.
* In the most cases [materialized map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html) is faster and simpler, so it is better to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything at all like

> map is the equivalent to collect for Java

in the linked page. The only mention of `collect` is

> > One benefit of this is that there's no need for an initial conversion from a Collection into a Stream, and no need for a final conversion from a Stream back into a collection – using the collect() calls.

and `map()` is just an example here; it could equally be `filter`, `flatMap`, some sequence thereof, etc.

So it's saying both `stream()` and `collect(Collectors.toList())` can be thrown out (but only together!) and possibly some methods need to be renamed.